# Process RTSP with Node.js for taking an image snapshot

Tags: javascript, node.js, rtsp

I have a RTSP that I would love to make Node.JS understand. I found a way to do it [using Java taking a capture from a webcam](http://badankles.com/?p=209) but I would love to just use Node.js on this task and get it from a video RTSP'd.

My intention is to use setInterval, grab the stream, convert it to base64 and stream it through Socket.IO to a client so they can see it as a `<img>` tag on their browser. Much of this will be taken from [the guy who make it with a webcam](http://badankles.com/?p=209) but I only have a RTSP available as video-source.

So, does anyone knows if there's a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I really found the answer months ago but forgot I asked here.

My code is at https://github.com/ghostbar/RTSP-Streaming.js. It reads it from an RTSP stream and converts it to JPEG, then to base64 in order to pass it via Socket.IO to the client.

Comment: Please follow the steps [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist) to merge your accounts. Also please post some relevant code, don't just put link to external website holding the whole code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code with minimal dependencies which can read data from a Webcam and upload it to as an image on the server using Node: https://github.com/josher19/node-jpegcam

You could have it send the data to the client instead of saving it as an image on the server.

->> Josh <<-