# RTSP client library for Node.js without ffmpeg

Tags: javascript, node.js, rtsp

I am working on a Node.js proxy for media streaming. One of the use cases is to connect to a RTSP server and forward the incoming stream data through a number of different technologies. I have found quite a bit on RTSP server libraries for Node.js, but I cannot find (or I have found and misinterpreted) anything on RTSP clients in Node.js.

I need direct access to the stream data, as where that stream is forwarded is very open-ended. I am also not in direct control of the server environment; I have access to node and npm, and that's really it. I might be able to request certain software be installed, but I would prefer not having to go down that route.

Is there a library that can handle this?

**EDIT**

I have confirmed that ffmpeg will not be available to me. From the comments to this question, I have also determined that it is unlikely that a library exists for my use case that will also meet stability and performance concerns. Unless there are any last words, I am leaning towards this question being answered with a simple "nope."

Comment: this question has already been answered  times...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289421/process-rtsp-with-node-js-for-taking-an-image-snapshot?rq=1

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887877/rtp-rtsp-implementation-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: The first link links to a project that uses ffmpeg to set up a RTSP client, and the second one does not provide a library, but rather mentions the asker should find one. Neither answer my question, unless the answer is no.

Comment: if you do more search you will find that there is no other way, you can only convert using ffmpeg library, ffmpeg does have ports in js but they are unreliable https://bgrins.github.io/videoconverter.js/

So at end...you can't without ffmpeg...(there may exist some lib in c++ or other)..You can try Binding Nodejs and c++..

Comment: Sounds like those do even more than I am trying to do. I just want the frames from RTP; if it's streaming something encoded using H.264, I just need to grab the H.264 frames and send those on. I'll look more at what the ffmpeg libraries are doing and see if there's anything I can extract out of there. Worst case, I'll see if I can get ffmpeg added to the servers, but I am not confident that will happen. Thanks for the info.

Comment: https://ipcamlive.com/ They provide you API...Stream will be routed through their server( i don't recommend) instead getting a cheap vps will work...5$ a month just to run your server.